Google Kubernetes Engine overriding terminationGracePeriodSeconds to 600 seconds
My kubernetes cluster which is running in Autopilot mode overrides the value of  terminationGracePeriodSeconds property to 600. Same thing happens when I edit the yaml file over Google Cloud Console and value changes back to 600.
Is this a known and undocumented issue with the Autopilot or Google Kubernetes Engine? And if so, is there a work around?
Thanks for any help!

Autopilot clusters have a strict limit of 10mins

Autopilot clusters in GKE have strict limit of 10mins:
For automatic node upgrades, the grace period can be up to one hour. For scale-down events, the grace period can be up to 10 minutes.

